# For text classification with scikit-learn, do I have to use both, Countvectorizer and TFIDF?

Tags: text, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

Looking through scikit-learn documentation code, it suggests to implement the Countvectorizer first and then on top TFIDF. Can I use only TFIDF?
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9VEH.png)

If I only use TFIDF and I give my preprocessed texts as input it won't take the data type (I tried as a list and a np array). Can someone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. In the example they show, they use on top of `CountVectorizer` a `TfidfTransformer`. Using directly `TfidfVectorizer` produces the same result. Thus, it is up to you to chose which weighting scheme you want.
2. I don't understand really well your question. Scikit vectorizers can have different types of input, ranging from list/arrays of strings to file descriptor and others. To construct the ngrams, it uses the argument `tokenizer=` and `preprocessor=`. What is your issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

CV and TFIDF work differently, I can use only CV but I wasn't able to use TFIDF without CV, so I was just wondering. If it produces the same result it should be fine. Thanks.

Comment: Then maybe resolve the question